# FTDI Bit-Bang Jitter (FT232R vs FT232H)

Tags: usb, microcontroller, ftdi, jitter, oscilloscope

When I bit-bang the RX and TX pins on the FT232H, output is beautiful. When I repeat on the FT232R it is awful. **What is causing signals to look so bad on the FT232R?** Note that I'm using a FT232R breakout board ([from sparkfun](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/sparkfun-electronics/BOB-13263/1568-1720-ND/)) and a FT232H breakout board ([from ADAfruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2264)).

[image]

The image above is from this C# program running on both breakout boards:

```c
const byte PIN_TX = 0b00000001;
const byte PIN_RX = 0b00000010;

public static FTDI ftdi = new FTDI();
public static FTDI.FT_STATUS ft_status = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;
public static UInt32 bytesWritten = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // open and configure the FTDI device
    ftdi.OpenByIndex(0);
    ftdi.SetBitMode(0, 0);
    ftdi.SetBitMode(PIN_TX | PIN_RX, 0x01); // Asynchronous Bit Bang Mode
    ftdi.SetBaudRate(9600);

    // create some data to send
    byte[] data = new byte[1234];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
        if (i % 2 == 1) data[i] |= PIN_RX;
        if (i % 4 == 1) data[i] |= PIN_TX;
    }

    while (true)
    {
        ftdi.Write(data, data.Length, ref bytesWritten);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently **this is a known problem with FT232R**.
It is addressed in the [FT232R errata](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_120_FT232R%20Errata%20Technical%20Note.pdf) (page 4) and demonstrated on these web pages:

- http://blog.bitheap.net/2012/03/ft232r-bitbang-mode-is-broken.html
- https://stb-tester.com/blog/2016/05/26/ir-post-mortem

Comment: Like everybody I can confirm that the bug was still there as 2016/2017.

One thing I noticed is that if you make your own FT232R board with an external clock, the issue goes away.

https://ftorres.azurewebsites.net/images/MadeInTheUSB/Devices/Nusbio.Board.Purple.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is an Errata that is supposed to only be Revision A of the FT232R.  However, I can confirm that this is still broken in 2019.